# Change the look and feel of admin pages

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, admin

I want to change the look and feel of the post edit page without making changes to any of the wordpress core file, which is basically a theme.  For example, for any user with role of 'author', i want to display everything in one column and re-arrange the meta boxes.
So is it possible to create a theme for one of the admin pages and how could i get started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The admin area can definitely be themed, using either CSS, a plugin, or a combination of both.  To get started, read the Codex page on [Creating Admin Themes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Admin_Themes).

To expand further - any overriding of core WP functions must be done from a plugin.  It's fairly simple, and just like any other function override - either adding the content with a new function and `add action` or with a filter to replace the existing function with your new function using `add_filter`